# How to resolve connection timeout expired in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I retrieve a large data from my database as list of json data using ASP.NET Web API, but I get this error in browser consol:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()`

and this error in browser page:

```
"InnerException": {
       "Message": "An error has occurred.",
       "ExceptionMessage": "The wait operation timed out",
       "ExceptionType": "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception",
       "StackTrace": null
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

This is my code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server = ...; database = ...; Integrated Security=false;
                    user id = ...; password = ...; Max Pool Size=2097151;");

public IHttpActionResult Getusers()
{
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from usersnotifications", con); 
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        da.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            return Ok(dt);
        }
        else
        {
            return Ok("No data found ...");
        }
}
```

- ***Note*** : this code work if I retrave little data.

Comment: Basics: do you **really** need **ALL** columns from `Users` ? If not - use `SELECT col1, col2, col3, ..., colN from Users` to fetch **only those columns** you really need. Second: do you need all **rows** from the `Users` table? If not : add a `WHERE` clause to limit the data being returned. Third: have you checked the execution plan of your SQL query? What does it tell you? Can you add an index or do something else to make the SQL run faster?